# My ruby code in .erb files lost indentation when I save in vscode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I was working on a file generated by devise, and when I save the changes the entire code auto-formatted and it seems to lost the indentation, I don't know how else describe it.

It went from this

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

To this

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
</div>


<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

I tried installing https://github.com/ruby-formatter/rufo with the vscode extenstion `Rufo - Ruby formatter` but change nothing.

How can I config vscode to avoid this happening?

Answer (score 3):

To edit your settings in settings.json, start by opening the Command Palette with CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P.

From the Command Palette, you have a choice between two commands that edit your settings:

- The Open Settings (UI) command will open a user-friendly UI to edit the settings JSON file indirectly.
- The Open Settings (JSON) command will let you directly edit the settings JSON file.

Click on **Open Settings (UI)** option then type save in search settings and uncheck the **Format on Save**

[image]